# Use alias in the same query with MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have this query:

```
SELECT BIL_Date, 
(BIL_Rate*BIL_Quantity) AS BIL_RateNonTaxed, 
(((BIL_Rate*BIL_Quantity)*SUM(STX_Amount)/100)+BIL_Rate*BIL_Quantity) AS BIL_RateTaxed, 
BIL_Status 
FROM ___BillableDatas 
LEFT JOIN ___SalesTaxes 
ON FIND_IN_SET(STX_Id, BIL_ApplicableTaxes) > 0
```

Each time I want to use a calculated amount with SQL, I need to repeat the operation.

For example, I need to repeat `BIL_Rate*BIL_Quantity` 3 times whereas it was stored into `BIL_RateNonTaxed`.

How can I use `BIL_RateNonTaxed` in the same query ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you calculate BIL_RateNonTaxed in a subquery, you can then reference the name and do the higher level calculations in the parent query. In MS Transact-SQL, this can be done with the CROSS APPLY operator, but I don't think MySQL has that functionality.